# Is there any way to get more candles/actions in-game

Tags: fallen-london

In Fallen London, the Story Nexus game, is there any way to get more candles/actions in-game. I mean without paying to become an "Exceptional Friend" with real money.

I am thinking of something similar to Kingdom of Loathing where you could eat food/drink booze to get more actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without spending money on Nex (the paid equivalent to Fate), there are a few ways to refresh candles:

- Spending fate

> Clicking on the Restore Actions buttons on the Fate page will refill your candle with your chosen number of actions. Note that Fate is occasionally rewarded at the end of long or difficult chains of Storylets, or as a reward for answering the occasional questionnaire.

- Drinking Darkdrop Coffee

> If somebody registers for Fallen London using your invite, you earn some Darkdrop Coffee, which you can use too refill your actions - info from [Lohoris](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97153/12937)

[Source - must be logged](http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/Gap/Load?content=/Storylet/Available#actions) and
[wiki page about coffee](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Darkdrop_Coffee).

Comment: Not completely correct: (1) fate costs money, (2) you can also use coffee IIRC

Comment: Since echoing no longer works, I've proposed an edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

- Drinking Darkdrop Coffee

There's a special item named Darkdrop Coffee which you can drink to refill your candles. You get it when someone signs in following your invitation.

Comment: First time hear about coffee.

Comment: @iber is 'echoing an action' still valid? I can't find it anywhere...

Comment: @vaxquis I think it isn't: it has been broken for a long time, and they must eventually have removed it.